# bluetooth questions from linux noob

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, bluetooth

I've actually got several questions, but one at a time.

My main question is regarding bluetooth. Sometimes (not always) on boot, just before the login screen appears, I get the message, "49.172836] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000". The message also sometimes appears on shutdown/reboot. I've seen other questions with similar error codes, but none appeared to apply to my issue. When logged in, bluetooth appears to work superficially. The only bluetooth devices I have are a PS3 and PS4 controller. The computer appears to recognize the controllers fine, but I keep getting pop-ups over and over saying "bluetooth is connected", then "bluetooth is disconnected" over and over. The pairing with either controller eventually fails with "i/o error".

I also appear to have 2 different bluetooth manager apps installed, but I'm not 100% sure of that.  I have the 2 "BlueDevil" apps in "System Tools", but it appears there is another one as well that does not appear in the "System Tools" menu.  This morning, I noticed there are 2 bluetooth tabs on my taskbar at the bottom (there was only one last night). Both tabs have the exact same right-click menu.

I guess I'm asking which is the correct bluetooth app, and how to remove the other one.

I'm running Lubuntu 20.04.4, if that matters.

---

Requested Edit --

I did not install anything specifically bluetooth related, but it is possible that something I grabbed from Discover may have had some bluetooth stuff bundled in it.

Out put from suggested Terminal command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express) [168c:0024] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0087]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Have you at some point installed something Bluetooth related? Perhaps trying to fix something? Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command and the info requested.